# Frequent ZooKeeper CONNECTIONLOSS events?

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, apache-zookeeper

I'm writing an application that uses ZooKeeper, and I'm getting frequent `CONNECTIONLOSS` events. I'm using `2000` as my tick time, `12000` as my session timeout, and the application is running in Amazon EC2. I believe I'm waiting for ZooKeeper to connect before I use it; here's the code I'm using to do that:

```
ZooKeeper zk=new ZooKeeper(connectionString, sessionTimeout, new Watcher() {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void process(WatchedEvent event) {
        switch(event.getState()) {
        case SyncConnected:
        case ConnectedReadOnly:
            // We're connected, count down...
            ready.countDown();
            break;
        case SaslAuthenticated:
            // Life is good here. Nothing to do...
            break;
        case AuthFailed:
        case Disconnected:
        case Expired:
        case NoSyncConnected:
        case Unknown:
        default:
            LOGGER.error("ZooKeeper event: "+event.getState());
            break;
        }
    }
});

boolean ok;
try {
    ok = ready.await(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
catch(InterruptedException e) {
    throw new InterruptedIOException();
}
if(ok == false)
    throw new IOException("Failed to connect to ZooKeeper");
```

Why might by ZooKeeper be getting these spurious `CONNECTIONLOSS` events?

Comment: Does it still happen with a 20000, or 40000 timeout?

Comment: I determined the issue. I was making a large request and needed to update `jute.maxbuffer` for it to work properly. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

We used to have similar ZK issues when running on AWS.  We solved them by ensuring that all of our EC2 instances were running with Network Time Protocol (NTP).  If your instances have time skew that seems to led to them being confused about timeouts.